# Firemonkey TListBox changing background color at runtime

Tags: firemonkey, tlistbox

I there a way, at runtime, other than using styles, to change the background color of a TListBox? Can I use the OnPaint event?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `TListbox` doesn't have a property to change the background color, I can only think of the following, which is based on combining two components, of which one (the `TListBox`) uses a built-in style. Note however, that this is not depending on `TStyleBook` nor any of the style files supplied with Delphi Firemonkey.

Place a `TRectangle` as a background for the `TListBox`. Set its `Fill` - `Color` property to a color you like. (I used "Cornsilk" in the example).

Place the `TListBox` on the rectangle as a child of the rectangle. In the "Object Inspector" locate the `StyleLookup` property and change its value to `transparentlistboxstyle`. This makes the listbox transparent and the rectangle and its fill color to shine through.

If you make the `TListBox` one pixel smaller than the rectangle on each side, you can use the `Sides` property to provide a thin frame around the listbox. Or you can choose to make them equally sized and not show any frame.

My test result looks like this:

[image]

The `TRectangle` and the `TListbox` properties from the `.fmx` file:

```
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akBottom]
    Fill.Color = claCornsilk
    Position.X = 7.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 361.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 219.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    object ListBox1: TListBox
      Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]
      Position.X = 1.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 1.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 359.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 217.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'transparentlistboxstyle'
      TabOrder = 0
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = False
      DisableFocusEffect = True
      ItemHeight = 48.000000000000000000
      DefaultItemStyles.ItemStyle = 'listboxitemrightdetail'
      DefaultItemStyles.GroupHeaderStyle = ''
      DefaultItemStyles.GroupFooterStyle = ''
      Viewport.Width = 359.000000000000000000
      Viewport.Height = 217.000000000000000000
    end
  end
```

To change the color of `ListBox1`, you actually change the color of the `TRectangle`:

```
procedure TForm5.ColorListBox1ItemClick(const Sender: TCustomListBox;
  const Item: TListBoxItem);
begin
  Rectangle1.Fill.Color := TColorListBox(Sender).Color;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an option. Still, I was wondering if I can change the background color of the `TListBox` using the `OnPaint` event. Do you think this is possible?