# Firemonkey TListBox changing background color of item rows at runtime

Tags: listbox, firemonkey

Is there a way, at runtime, other than using styles, to change the background color of item rows of a TListBox? Can I use the OnPaint event?

Comment: I vote to close this question, you already post the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75196388/firemonkey-tlistbox-changing-background-color-at-runtime

Comment: @Bosshoss Actually, the two questions are different, The question you linked to asked for a common background for the whole `TListBox`. This question asks for individual backgrounds for each item. Although not mentioned, would need to scroll with the items, etc.

Comment: there is any reason you don't want to use Style ?

Comment: @Bosshoss. IMO, Firemonkey styles are a bit tricky. Also the documentation is very poor. After trying hard to configure my own styles upon standard components, I wasn't able to achieve the desired outcome, hence, I gave up. I assume my inhability for this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Can I use the `OnPaint` event?"

Yes, you can. But maybe it is not considered the orthodox way, as it isn't made available and may fall apart in future Delphi releases. Anyway, if you want to try it, here goes:

You want to use the `OnPaint` event of the `TListBoxItem` class. However, `OnPaint` event of the item is not made available in the designer, so you will need to add it manually to your form class.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    // add following manually (copy & paste)
    procedure ListBoxItemPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; 
      const ARect: TRectF);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure PopulateListBox;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

Then, when you add items to `ListBox1`, it is important to assign `ListBoxItemPaint` to each items `OnPaint` event (see end of procedure):

```
procedure TForm1.PopulateListBox;
var
  i: integer;
  item: TListBoxItem;
begin
  // Set default item height
  // Individual heights are not possible
  ListBox1.ItemHeight := 48;
  // Set nr of columns, items arranged horizontally first, then vertically
  ListBox1.Columns := 1; // 3;
  // Add items
  for i := 0 to 7 do
  begin
    item := TListBoxItem.Create(nil);
    item.Parent := ListBox1;
    item.Width := Listbox1.Width;
    item.StyledSettings := [];    // You are now responsible for corresponding
                                  // item.TextSettings, e.g. font, style, color etc.
    item.tag := i;
    item.Text := 'Item ' + IntToStr(i);
    item.OnPaint := ListBoxItemPaint;   // This links the OnPaint event to your code
  end;
end;
```

And this is the `ListBoxItemPaint()` procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBoxItemPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
var
  Brush: TBrush;
  Color: TAlphaColor;
  Txt: string;
  LocRect: TRectF;
begin
  begin
    Txt := (Sender as TListBoxItem).Text;
    case (Sender as TListBoxItem).Tag of
      0: Color := TAlphaColors.Aliceblue;
      1: Color := TAlphaColors.Antiquewhite;
      2: Color := TAlphaColors.Aqua;
      3: Color := TAlphaColors.Aquamarine;
      4: Color := TAlphaColors.Azure;
      5: Color := TAlphaColors.Beige;
      6: Color := TAlphaColors.Bisque;
    else
         Color := TAlphaColorRec.Chocolate;
    end;

    // Item background, color and shape
    Brush := TBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, Color);
    try
      Canvas.FillRect(ARect, 1, Brush); // rectangular item band
//    alternatively use rounded corners
//      Canvas.FillRect(ARect,11, 11, AllCorners, 1, Brush); // rounded corners
    finally
      Brush.Free;
    end;

    // Text color, font, style and size
    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;
    Canvas.Font.Family := 'Segoe UI';
    Canvas.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold, TFontStyle.fsItalic];
    Canvas.Font.Size := 16;

    // Item text location and drawing
    LocRect := ARect;
    LocRect.Left := LocRect.Left + 10;
    Canvas.FillText(LocRect, Txt, False, 1, [], TTextAlign.Leading, TTextAlign.Leading);
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Code is written and tested with Delphi 10.4 and demonstrates how you can have different bg colors for each item in a `TListBox`.

To change the color of the items at run time you need to move the color selection out from the `OnPaint` to a lookup function with selection logic you want to use.

Comment: Thanks. I will take in account your alert about future Delphi versions.

Comment: I know that is a different question and appologize for that. Is it possible to achieve same effect, at runtime, with styles?

Comment: Some time ago somebody else asked you about why not use styles, and then you answered in line with you don't know how to use styles. Anyway, [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38219295/2292722). I can not right now check myself, but maybe tomorrow or the day after. If you get started but hit a problem, post a new question, **and include code that you have so far**.

Comment: Yes, about that subject, I was talking of using styles at design time, now I'm talking of using at runtime.

Comment: I'll check, in a couple of days, if you had posted any comment regarding using styles at runtime. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, I repeat what I said in my previous comment: *post a new question, **and include code that you have so far**.* I don't see any new question posted by you.